# How to find the Empty city dropdown in the below image?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-rc

Functionality: We have three fields Country, State, City -

[image]

After select the Country it reveal the States list and after select the state it reveal the city list.

Question: In this some states don't have cities, so how find country, states list those not have cities list using selenium?

i tried the code below like this but loop is not working & not shows the empty list

```
@Test
public void findstate() throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("URL");
    Select country = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UserProfileCountryId']")));
    List<WebElement> countrylist = country.getOptions();
    System.out.println(countrylist.size());
    for (int i = 1; i <= countrylist.size(); i++) {
        countrylist.get(i).click();
        Select state = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UserProfileStateId']")));
        List<WebElement> statelist = state.getOptions();
        for (int j = 1; j <= statelist.size(); j++) {
            statelist.get(j).click();
            Select city = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UserProfileCityId']")));
            List<WebElement> citylist = city.getOptions();
            System.out.println("Country, state list of Empty Cities");
            if (citylist.size() > 1) {
                System.out.println(countrylist.get(i).getText() + "-----" + statelist.get(j).getText() + "-----");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

**Source Code for Country, State, City:**

```html
<span class="select-wrapper"><select name="data[UserProfile][country_id]" class="custom-select valid" id="UserProfileCountryId" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true">
<option value="">Country</option>
<option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="2">Albania</option>
</select><span class="holder">Afghanistan</span></span>
<select name="data[UserProfile][state_id]" class="custom-select valid" id="UserProfileStateId" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true">
<option value="">State</option>
<option value="42">Badakhshan</option>
<option value="43">Badgis</option>
<option value="44">Baglan</option>
</select>
<select name="data[UserProfile][city_id]" class="custom-select valid" id="UserProfileCityId" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true">
<option value="">City</option>
<option value="5916">Andarab</option>
<option value="5917">Baghlan</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i added the source code also

Comment: i want your html source code

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos due to copy&paste I think.

You need to use the correct `Select` variables in your loops, but you always use `country`.

Try this:

```
@Test
public void findstate() throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("URL");
    Select country = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UserProfileCountryId']")));
    List<WebElement> countrylist = country.getOptions();
    System.out.println(countrylist.size());
    for (int i = 1; i <= countrylist.size(); i++) {
        countrylist.get(i).click();
        Select state = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UserProfileStateId']")));
        List<WebElement> statelist = state.getOptions();
        for (int j = 1; j <= statelist.size(); j++) {
            statelist.get(j).click();
            Select city = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UserProfileCityId']")));
            List<WebElement> citylist = city.getOptions();
            System.out.println("Country, state list of Empty Cities");
            if (citylist.size() > 1) {
                System.out.println(countrylist.get(i).getText() + "-----" + statelist.get(j).getText() + "-----");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

To avoid this error it might be better to use foreach loops like this:

```
for (WebElement element : country.getOptions()) { }
```

I don't know your HTML code, but it might also be **necessary to wait for the other dropdowns to fill with elements** before asking `getOptions()`. Selenium is very very fast and it might ask for the options of the dropdown before they are loaded by your site. In this case you will not get any results even using the updated code.

Try to wait for the dropdowns to fill like this every time:

```
    Select country = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UserProfileCountryId']")));
    List<WebElement> countrylist = country.getOptions();
    System.out.println(countrylist.size());
    for (WebElement element : countrylist) {
        element.click();
        Select state = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UserProfileStateId']")));

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver webdriver) {
           return state.getOptions() > 1;
           }
        });

        List<WebElement> statelist = state.getOptions();
        ....
```

You do the same for city-options -> if you run into a timeout you found the state that has no cities...

Comment: i entered code is fine but but have to use wait commands loading time as you said, but i am not get how to use this wait commands b/w of this code?
i tried wait commands but getting another errors

Comment: hey man, updated my answer to show you how to wait for a certain condition - in this case until the dropdown is populated with more than one element

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try like below

```
@Test
public void findstate() throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("URL");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    Select country = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UserProfileCountryId']")));
    List<WebElement> countrylist = country.getOptions();
    System.out.println(countrylist.size());
    for (int i = 0; i <= countrylist.size(); i++) {
        countrylist.get(i).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='UserProfileStateId']")));
        Select state = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UserProfileStateId']")));
        // here use state not country
        List<WebElement> statelist = state.getOptions();
        for (int j = 0; j <= statelist.size(); j++) {
            statelist.get(j).click();
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='UserProfileCityId']")));
            Select city = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UserProfileCityId']")));
         // here use city not country
            List<WebElement> citylist = city.getOptions();
            for (int k = 0; k <= citylist.size(); k++) {
                citylist.get(k).click();
                System.out.println("Country, state list of Empty Cities");
                if (citylist.get(k).getText() == null) {
                    System.out.println(countrylist.get(i).getText() + "-----" + statelist.get(j).getText() + "-----"+ citylist.get(k).getText());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnaks for the reply raj,
but i got error when running this
"org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //*[@id='UserProfileStateId']"

Answer (score 0):

In the outermost loop select country and then in an inner loop select each state for that country and check if city is found. If not then get the city & country & go on this way.

I think, it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

its worked fine, add the 'tab' key after select the country

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='UserProfileCountryId']")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

But I got another problem while executing, After some time run the script i got error
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds

Thanks for answers